# Save output of running java program as String[]

Tags: java

I have the following java code that prints stuff to the console

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jmol.adapter.smarter.SmarterJmolAdapter;
import org.jmol.api.JmolViewer;
import org.jmol.util.Logger;
import org.openscience.jmol.app.jmolpanel.AppConsole;

public class Integrate {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JMOL_WS_V1");
        frame.addWindowListener(new ApplicationCloser());
        frame.setSize(410, 700);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        JmolPanel jmolPanel = new JmolPanel();
        jmolPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        // main panel -- Jmol panel on top

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(jmolPanel);

        // main panel -- console panel on bottom

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        AppConsole console = new AppConsole(jmolPanel.viewer, panel2,
        "History State Clear");

        jmolPanel.viewer.setJmolCallbackListener(console);

        panel.add("South", panel2);

        contentPane.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //STARTUP SCRIPT

        String strError = jmolPanel.viewer.openFile("1644_____.pdb");
        if (strError == null){

                 //THIS IS THE COMMAND THAT CALCULATES STUFF
                jmolPanel.viewer.evalString("measure 3 4");
                jmolPanel.viewer.evalString("measure 2 4");
            }else{
                Logger.error(strError);
        }

    }

    static class ApplicationCloser extends WindowAdapter {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    static class JmolPanel extends JPanel {

        JmolViewer viewer;

        private final Dimension currentSize = new Dimension();

        JmolPanel() {
            viewer = JmolViewer.allocateViewer(this, new SmarterJmolAdapter(), 
            null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            getSize(currentSize);
            viewer.renderScreenImage(g, currentSize.width, currentSize.height);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints this in the console:

```
(C) 2012 Jmol Development
Jmol Version: 13.0.12  2013-01-23 21:55
java.vendor: Apple Inc.
java.version: 1.6.0_41
os.name: Mac OS X
Access: ALL
memory: 10.8/85.0
processors available: 4
useCommandThread: false

FileManager.getAtomSetCollectionFromFile(1644_____.pdb)
FileManager opening /Users/juliofdiaz/Dropbox/CF/1644_____.pdb
The Resolver thinks Pdb
openFile(1644_____.pdb): 119 ms
reading 2602 atoms
ModelSet: haveSymmetry:false haveUnitcells:false haveFractionalCoord:false
1 model in this collection. Use getProperty "modelInfo" or getProperty "auxiliaryInfo" to inspect them.
Default Van der Waals type for model set to Jmol
2602 atoms created
Time to autoBond: 58 ms
ModelSet: autobonding; use  autobond=false  to not generate bonds automatically
Jmol 13.0.12  2013-01-23 21:55 DSSP analysis for model 1.1 - null

W. Kabsch and C. Sander, Biopolymers, vol 22, 1983, pp 2577-2637

We thank Wolfgang Kabsch and Chris Sander for writing the DSSP software,
and we thank the CMBI for maintaining it to the extent that it was easy to
re-engineer for our purposes. At this point in time, we make no guarantee
that this code gives precisely the same analysis as the code available via license
from CMBI at http://swift.cmbi.ru.nl/gv/dssp

All bioshapes have been deleted and must be regenerated.

measurement[0] = [[MET]1.CB #3, [MET]1.C #4, 0.219 nm]
measurement[1] = [[MET]1.CA #2, [MET]1.C #4, 0.143 nm]
```

I would like to capture all the output from this program in an array of Strings (Each String item would be each line). I have played around with getting the BufferedReader for this Process but do to my lack ok experience with this class I fail to know how to assign the current Runtime to a Process. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Can't you just redirect the stdout from the printing program to some reader in the reading program? That way, you could read the output line by line, and store them in an array.

Comment: @Chiel92 Im not sure what this means?

Comment: Regarding at what @Chiel92 said, take a look at [System.setOut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream))

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`
`out = new PrintStream(baos);`
`oldOut = System.getOut();` 
`System.setOut(out);`
`ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());`

Comment: @yohlulz what is the reason for oldOut = System.getOut()

Comment: Cause it's just a code snippet, that `in` could also be wrapped with a `BufferedReader` for `readLine` and so on

Comment: oldOut = System.out, sorry about the typo, oldOut is just for backup reasons (matter of taste)

Comment: That is actually really useful because I do want to print something to the console once Im done processing the printstream

Comment: Does it need to be done inside the same JVM process? Otherwise it would be simple to read the output of a launched process either through `Process.getInputStream()` or by redirecting the standard output to a file at the OS level.

Comment: how do you start the program that writes to stdout ? is it stand alone or from the program where you want to capture the output in String[] using something like `System.getRuntime().exec("MyCommadThatWritesToStdout")` or a `new ProcessBuilder("MyCommadThatWritesToStdout").start()`

Comment: @EskoLuontola Im not sure how to run this program independent of the JVM Process. I have annotated the part of my code that runs the program

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to redirect the system output to a new one, use it, and restore the old one:

```
PrintStream systemOut = System.out;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(ps);
System.out.println("Test string");
String content = baos.toString("ISO-8859-1");  // A charset
System.setOut(systemOut);
System.out.println("Restored");
```

Note that this comment differs from the one of @yohlulz in that the toString() method decodes de data. The charset argument of toString is optional. The parameterless one will decode the output with the platform's default character. [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString%28%29)